# Adding a 0 in the beginning of a 2D numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

```
import numpy as np
import math as m
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

#Q1
def bm(s,n):
    np.random.seed(222)
    dw = np.random.normal(0,1,size=(s,n))*m.sqrt(1/n)
    w = np.cumsum(dw, axis=1)
    a = np.mean(w, axis=0)
    b = np.std(w, axis=0)
    plt.plot(np.arange(n),w[:10:,:].T)
    plt.plot(np.arange(n),a.T)
    plt.plot(np.arange(n),b.T)
    plt.show()

bm(1000,600)
```

This code creates Brownian Motions generated from random standard normal distributions.
Every graph needs to start at 0, so I need to append 0 to the beginning of each graph.
How can I do this?

Comment: Conventionally, `pyplot` is imported as `plt` rather than `pt`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always subtract off the first delta:

```
w = np.cumsum(dw, axis=1) - dw[:, :1]
```

The elements of `w` are normally given by

```
 dw[:, :1]
 dw[:, :1] + dw[:, 1:2]
 dw[:, :1] + dw[:, 1:2] + dw[:, 2:3]
 ...
```

Clearly removing `dw[:, :1]` offsets the sum by the first element. The difference between `dw[:, 0]` and `dw[:, :1]` is that the latter preserves the shape for proper broadcasting, as if you did `dw[:, 0][:, None]`. If you insist on removing the last element rather than the first, you can do

```
 w = np.empty_like(dw)
 np.cumsum(dw[:, :-1], axis=1, out=w[:, 1:])
 w[:, 0] = 0
```

You can actually prepend a zero in a couple of different ways. A concatenation is one way:

```
np.concatenate((np.zeros((dw.shape[0], 1)), np.cumsum(dw, axis=1)), axis=1)
```

A potentially better way, hinted above, might be to pre-allocate the output buffer:

```
w = np.empty((dw.shape[0], dw.shape[1] + 1))
np.cumsum(dw, axis=1, out=w[:, 1:])
w[:, 0] = 0
```

Comment: @user14369387. What does that mean?

Comment: I am trying to map this function so that it takes each x and turns these into e to the power (a+(b times x)), how can I do it?

Comment: I upvoted your answer afterwards :) and yes i just deleted it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222960/discussion-between-user14369387-and-mad-physicist).

Answer (score 1):

In general, you can use numpy.concatenate to append arrays.

But in this specific case, I'd just do

```
dw[:, 0] = 0.0
```

after you create `dw`.

Comment: Took me a second to realize that that won't alter the distribution of steps. Just the initial value.